# _remap function to redirect to different url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I my routes.php

```
I have the following routing to redirect to url:
$route['AccountTest/test']      = "Account/test";
$route['SalaryTest/test']      = salary/test";
```

How do i implement _remap() codeigniter function to do the same rather than using routes.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the route.php file for this.

```
$route['test1] = 'test1/contact;
$route['test2'] = 'test1/contact;
```

See https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: is it possible to use _remap() to achieve this by passing url as parameter?